# IF statement displaying only 1 variable regardless of results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where users can join groups and post topics related to that group, I am having an issue where regardless of the user result, it just shows "member" even on a test account that has no records in the database, can someone please explain what I am doing wrong, thank you.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['gid'];
$user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$iropen = "SELECT * FROM `group_users` WHERE user_id='$user' AND group_id='$id'"; 
$resultg = mysql_query($iropen);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultg);

if ($rows['accepted'] = 1) {
    echo 'member';
} else {
    echo 'pending';
}
if ($resultg < 1) {
    echo 'join';
}
?>
```

Comment: You want to use comparison operator not assignment operator in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($rows['accepted'] = 1) {
```

You need two `==` here.

```
if ($rows['accepted'] == 1) {
```

PHP's operator reference, if you need it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: thanks, that's gotten me closer, now on the account which doesn't have any record in the database it's displaying "pending" instead of "join".

Comment: And the old PHP `if($var=$something)` strikes again. It never fails to bring a big smirk to my face when I see these ones...

Answer (score 1):

What @vinodadhikary is saying is that you have single equal-sign instead of the double-equal-sign in your first IF clause.  It should be:
if ($rows['accepted'] == 1)...

Comment: does that apply even if the value in the database what I am looking for is 0 or 1?

Comment: As you have seen elsewhere in this post - the single equal sign is when you want to make a variable contain a value ($a = 1).  The double-equal sign is when you are asking a question: $a == 1 means "Is the value in $a the number 1?"  If it helps, you could look at it like this: $a ?= 1  (?= means 'does it equal?').
Also as was stated before, this is not an uncommon mistake for people to make.  It just takes some getting used to - soon, it will become natural/habitual for you (grin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['gid'];
$user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$iropen = "SELECT * FROM `group_users` WHERE user_id='".$user."' AND group_id='".$id."'"; 
if($resultg = mysql_query($iropen)){
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultg)
}

if (mysql_num_rows($resultg) < 1) {
    echo 'join';
}else if ($rows['accepted'] == 1) {
    echo 'member';
} else {
    echo 'pending';
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks i gave it a go but got.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /****/includes/widgets/group_panel.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /****/includes/widgets/group_panel.php on line 9
join

Comment: Please see the update. I have change my answer.
replace `if($resultg = mysql_query($iropen)){
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultg);
}`

instead of `$resultg = mysql_query($iropen);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultg);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['gid'];
    $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $iropen = "SELECT * FROM `group_users` WHERE user_id='$user' AND group_id='$id'"; 
    $resultg = mysql_query($iropen);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultg);
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($resultg);


    if ($num_results < 1) {
        echo "join";
    } else if ($rows['accepted'] == 1) {
        echo "member";
    } else {
        echo "pending";
    }
?>
```